# Nginx: Redirect all non-existing requests to index.php

Tags: php, url-rewriting, nginx

I'm in the midst of migrating over to Nginx, from Apache.

I'm currently using a custom content management solution that utilizes the SERVER['request_uri'] to handle routing.

What I am trying to do is redirect all non-existing files & directory requests to /index.php, and not update the clients uri. However, when a file does exist, I want to return that instead.

An example url would be:
localhost/content/page/1 <- Should populate $_SERVER['request_uri'] to be /content/page/1
Or
localhost/public/script/exists.js <- Should be returned as an actual file.

Answer (score 10):

You need to add a `location /` block or update your current `location /` block in your nginx **vhost** file.

This will redirect all request to the `index.php` if the file or directory is not found:

```
location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php;
}
```

This goes inside your server directive, for more information visit http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpCoreModule

After you modify your vhost file you need to **restart nginx**

**Note:** The try_files directive for server blocks was added in 0.7.44

Comment: BTW, how can I get the redirected file name in php?

Comment: this even don't work when you put .php extension on the request. for example http://example.com/notexisting.php will result to the 404 instead of rewriting to index.php

Comment: This answer is incomplete as it will not redirect requests to non existent PHP files. Any request ending in *.php will get a 404 response and not be redirected.

Comment: To make this work with non existing PHP scripts too, in addition to the answer of PhearOfRayne, you have to specify that fastcgi must only be used for `index.php`. Using `Location /index.php { fastcgi_pass... }` instead of `Location / { fastcgi_pass... }`.

This assumes that you have no other scripts but `index.php`.