# Nginx redirect all traffic to index.php, but don't allow arbitrary file access

Tags: php, nginx

I have a legacy PHP app (Zend Framework) that I'm moving from Apache to Nginx. Except for things like web files (JS, CSS, images, fonts, etc.), all traffic needs to go through the `index.php` file in the root of the project folder. So I need to redirect all traffic to `index.php`, except for web files.

There are a lot of solutions to this that use `try_files` as a catch-all. Basically if a file is not found on the filesystem, nginx will send the request to `index.php`.

The problem with this is that the app stores its configuration file in a web-accessible path (i.e. in a subdirectory of the folder that holds `index.php`). So you could point your browser to the configuration file path and read it (e.g. `https://example.com/config/app.xml`). Since the file exists on the filesystem, nginx will serve it. There are actually a few more project config files that can be accessed in this way too.

So, how do I send all requests to `index.php`, except for web files, and also not allow arbitrary files to be read from the web?

Yes, I know I could update the app to access the config files in another location, but it's legacy and not super crucial. I don't want to spend more time on it than I have to and I don't want to break it.

I could also forbid access to any extensions that happen to be config files (e.g. `xml`, `yml`, etc.), but it's a big project and I don't want to risk missing something.

I figured out a solution. I didn't find anything that worked exactly the way I wanted online, so I'm asking this question in order to answer it.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14000451/nginx-redirect-all-non-existing-requests-to-index-php

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looking at [your configuration](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64838933/1526406) I have a strong desire to comment it, however this would be much beyond the single comment format so writing this as an answer.

> ```
> location ~* \.(js|ico|gif|jpg|png|svg|css|jpeg|wav|mp3|eot|woff|ttf)$ {}
> ```

Of course, this would work. But in a real life this would effectively blocking the files such as `robots.txt`, `sitemap.xml`, preventing SSL certificate validation via the `/.well-known/pki-validation/<signature>.txt` etc.

> ```
> location ~* ^/(?!(index\.php)) {
>   rewrite ^ /index.php$is_args$args;
> }
> ```

Both `rewrite` and `location` directives works with the normalized URI (which doesn't include the query part of the request). While the `try_files` or `return` directives usually require this `$is_args$args` suffix to be used, with the `rewrite` directive all the query arguments are preserved and follows the rewritten URI. This means the `/users?blah=1` request is being rewrited to - surprise, surprise - `/index.php?blah=1?blah=1`. This makes nginx consider the last `?blah=1` to be a query string and the preceding `/index.php?blah=1` to be the filename giving you "HTTP 404 Not found" error. The right way to write this location would be the

```
location ~* ^/(?!index\.php) {
  rewrite ^ /index.php last;
}
```

and it can be even more simple:

```
location / {
  rewrite ^ /index.php last;
}

location = /index.php { # instead of ~ \.php$
  ...
}
```

However if you want to pass all the other requests to your `index.php` controller it could be done in a much more effective way. I assume the `snippets/fastcgi-php.conf` file you are using is the default one from some Debian-based Linux distro:

> ```
> # regex to split $uri to $fastcgi_script_name and $fastcgi_path
> fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
>
> # Check that the PHP script exists before passing it
> try_files $fastcgi_script_name =404;
>
> # Bypass the fact that try_files resets $fastcgi_path_info
> # see: http://trac.nginx.org/nginx/ticket/321
> set $path_info $fastcgi_path_info;
> fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $path_info;
>
> fastcgi_index index.php;
> include fastcgi.conf;
> ```

You don't need it at all, as you don't need the `location ~ \.php$ { ... }` since the only PHP file you want to allow access to is the `index.php`. Use the following:

```
location / {
  # define the default FastCGI parameters
  include fastcgi.conf;
  # always use the 'index.php' as the FastCGI script
  fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root/index.php;
  # pass the request to the FastCGI backend
  fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.4-fpm.sock;
}
```

The whole configuration will be the

```
server {
  root /path/to/www;

  location ~* \.(js|ico|gif|jpg|png|svg|css|jpeg|wav|mp3|eot|woff|ttf)$ {}

  location / {
    include fastcgi.conf;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root/index.php;
    fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.4-fpm.sock;
  }
}
```

---

**Update @ 2022.05.17**

Since the new media file types and formats comes to the scene time to time, requiring you to add those types and change the nginx configuration every time it happens, if one day you'd decide to switch from the *list all the allowed* to *list all the denied* approach, the most optimal way to do it can be the following:

```
# deny hidden files and files with the extensions listed below
location ~ /\.|\.(?:xml|yml|php|phar|inc)$ {
    deny all;
}

location / {
    try_files $uri /index.php$is_args$args;
    # cache policy for the static files can be added here
}

location = /index.php {
    include fastcgi.conf;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root/index.php;
    fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.4-fpm.sock;
}
```

Since the *exact match* locations takes precedence over the *regex match* ones, this will effectively block any PHP (or other listed types) file access while the `index.php` one will remain allowed.

Comment: Thanks! This is so helpful. I updated my answer to reflect a couple changes you suggested. I kept the `.php` matching block in since I think the way I have it now will make more senes to me when I look at it again in like a year :) This makes me want to learn nginx configuration a little better.

Comment: It's up to you, but this way you allow to execute any request for any PHP file, regex matching locations have a greater priority over the prefix locations. And all this `snippets/fastcgi-php.conf` content is really a mess as for me, I never use it in production.

Comment: Oh, so as it is, if someone knows the URL to a PHP file directly, they could access it without being directed to index.php?

Comment: Yes, exactly. If you want to prevent it, use at least `location = /index.php { ... }` instead of `location ~ \.php$ { ... }`, although I think my config is more optimized in terms of performance (I'm some kind of performance geek :) ).

Comment: Just updated. Thank you again. I've honestly learned more about nginx configuration in these few minutes than I have from looking at quite a few examples trying to get this working in the first place. I'm sure yours is more performant. Though performance won't be an issue with this. It just needs to stick around for a little while longer. I feel like I'll understand what I have now better if I need to make a change in the future.

Answer (score 2):

Here's the configuration I came up with (leaving out `listen`, `server_name`, etc. since they aren't important):

```
server {
  root /path/to/www;

  # this just catches all web files and allows them through
  location ~* \.(js|ico|gif|jpg|png|svg|css|jpeg|wav|mp3|eot|woff|ttf)$ {}

  # send all other traffic to index.php. this is important because it
  # blocks access to things like configuration.xml
  location / {
    rewrite ^ /index.php last;
  }

  location = /index.php {
    include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
    fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.4-fpm.sock;
  }
}
```

I'll go through each block and explain it's purpose.

```
location ~* \.(js|ico|gif|jpg|png|svg|css|jpeg|wav|mp3|eot|woff|ttf)$ {}
```

The first block catches all web files. The body of the block is empty, which just lets nginx send the matched files directly. You could add caching directives in here if you want.

```
location / {
  rewrite ^ /index.php last;
}
```

The second block sends all other traffic to `index.php`. Since the first block matches all the web files, this block won't apply to them. This is the block that prevents arbitrary files from being accessed from the web, since all of those file requests will be sent to `index.php` which will respond with a 404.

```
location = /index.php {
  include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
  fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.4-fpm.sock;
}
```

The last block is just to process PHP requests through FPM. Though, as [Ivan helpfully pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64841349/1526406), it's important to only target `index.php` otherwise any PHP file could be directly executed if someone knew the URL for it.

With all of this, I get:

1. If I access a JS, CSS, images, etc. they are served directly.
2. If I try to access a configuration file, I get a 404.
3. If I try to access one of the actions that the app knows about, it works.
4. Query parameters work as expected.

**EDIT:** After seeing [Ivan's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64841349/1526406) I was able to eliminate one block and simplify another. I updated the config to reflect the change.

Comment: One more thing to note - the index files are not used at all with this configuration, that `index index.php index.html index.htm;` line can be safely omitted.