# Nginx fastcgi reverse proxy for a PHP API, without need to serve static files

Tags: php, nginx, reverse-proxy, fastcgi

I'm trying to setup an nginx reverse proxy, deployed as a networked image in ECS. Behind it is a PHP API, running in a separate php-fpm container listening on port 9000. The nginx docs and examples I can find seem to suggest that it has to be configured with a `root` path within the server block in the config.

The following is an example (from [here](https://github.com/maurobonfietti/rest-api-slim-php/blob/master/docker/nginx/conf.d/default.conf)) of the nginx config that seems to be commonly used in this scenario:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    root /var/www/html/public;  # is this really needed if proxying all requests to php?
    server_name _;
    index index.php;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$is_args$args;
    }
    location ~ \.php$ {
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass php-fpm:9000;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_path_info;
    }
}
```

Looking at it from a performance perspective, when a request comes into an API endpoint such as `/api/foobar`, in this particular scenario there is no point in nginx trying to check the filesystem for an index file inside this folder, since we know for sure there is no such folder. Ideally it should bypass this unnecessary step and simply proxy the request straight to the other container that's running php-fpm, letting it deal with route matching and 404's if an unexpected route is requested.

So, my question is - given a requirement to only serve API requests via a PHP application with "virtual routes" served up via a single index.php entry point (such as Slim) with no need to serve up any static files from a "root" path - is there a way to configure nginx to just proxy all incoming requests using fastcgi_pass?

Comment: From my point of view - there is no need to use nginX at all in this case.

Comment: Sure, you can hardcode script path and use `fastcgi_pass` nginx directive even in a most simple prefix location like `location / { ... }`, see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64841349/7121513) answer. If you want to vary script path depending on used API route, it is possible too, check the last part of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62971843/7121513) answer.

Comment: @IVOGELOV - I've been wondering the same thing, if load balancing the app in ecs is the nginx layer really necessary... but was following the pattern here: https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/nginx-reverse-proxy-sidecar-container-on-amazon-ecs/

Comment: @IvanShatsky - thanks, I was just experimenting with setting:
fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root/index.php
This seems to work, but the app appears to be loosing context of the route path, even though I have this set: fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_path_info;

Comment: @IVOGELOV For example it can be used for SSL termination.

Comment: @RossAnthony Most modern PHP apps relying on `REQUEST_URI` PHP-FPM parameter value, I didn't see any use of `PATH_INFO` for years. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62971843/7121513) answer addresses tweaking of `REQUEST_URI` parameter value.

Comment: @IvanShatsky The AWS load balancer can terminate SSL connections and even provide you a free SSL certificate. The PHP app can use Swoole or similar reactive library to avoid PHP-FPM.

Comment: @IVOGELOV Thanks for the suggestion of Swoole, I will take a look into that option. Like you said, in this situation of a PHP API with no static files to serve up it really feels like Nginx is overkill and just adds unnecessary complexity to the build and pipeline.