# How to return 404 when php files are accessed except the index.php file?

Tags: php, nginx

I'm routing everything through an index.php file. I don't want anyone to have access directly to php files in my /var/www/html directory except index.php.

I have this to disable access to php files:

```
location ~ /*.php {
    return 404;
}
```

But unfortunately I still get a 404 for my index.php file.

I'm using the following to route everything through index.php:

```
location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
}
```

How can I get both of these to work simultaneously?

Comment: You'd probably want to look at setting your `allow/deny`'s in the location for your PHP scripts ([Read this](https://serverfault.com/q/667798))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With your configuration you return HTTP 404 Not Found for any request containing `php` substring at all:

```
'/*' + '.' + 'php'
 |      |      |
 |      |      +--- 'php' substring
 |      +---------- any single char
 +----------------- 0 or more '/' chars
```

I don't think it is really what you mean writing it. The right regex pattern to match anything ending with `.php` is the `\.php$` one. Check PCRE regex patterns syntax for an additional info.

To match all PHP files except `index.php` you can use exact match location (which has precedence over a regex matching location):

```
location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
}
location = /index.php {
    include fastcgi_params;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root/index.php;
    fastcgi_pass <your_PHP-FPM_backend>;
}
location ~ \.php$ { # will be used for any PHP request except 'index.php'
    return 404;
}
```

The same can be achieved using `^~` location modifier. If the longest matching prefix location has the `^~` modifier then regular expressions are not checked:

```
location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
}
location ^~ /index.php {
    include fastcgi_params;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root/index.php;
    fastcgi_pass <your_PHP-FPM_backend>;
}
location ~ \.php$ { # will be used for any PHP request except 'index.php'
    return 404;
}
```

If you have multiple `index.php` files in different directories, previous solutions won't work and you'll need to use two regex matching locations instead:

```
location / {
    index index.php;
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
}
location ~ /index\.php$ {
    include fastcgi_params;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $request_filename;
    fastcgi_pass <your_PHP-FPM_backend>;
}
location ~ \.php$ { # will be used for any PHP request except 'index.php'
    return 404;
}
```

This is the only configuration where location blocks order matters. `location ~ /index\.php$ { ... }` should be the first or any PHP file request will be blocked with the `location ~ \.php$ { ... }` one.

Check `location` directive [description](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#location) and [How nginx processes a request](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/request_processing.html#simple_php_site_configuration) documentation page for more info. You can also check [Nginx redirect all traffic to index.php, but don't allow arbitrary file access](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64838932/nginx-redirect-all-traffic-to-index-php-but-dont-allow-arbitrary-file-access) SO thread for some additional examples.

Comment: Thank you very much. This was exactly what I needed.

Comment: One question though - there is one directory I'd like to have access to, let's say it's mydomain.com/mySpecialFolder. Is there a way to allow access to that?

Comment: I'm not sure I'm correctly understand your question. You want to allow access for PHP files in that directory? Or deny access to any file that isn't in that directory except `/index.php`?

Comment: I want what you gave me, it works just right. I just want to allow all files in mySpecialFolder to operate correctly and be directly accessible (including many php files). If that complicates things too much then don't worry about it.

Comment: Ok, you can try `location ~ ^/(index|mySpecialFolder/.+)\.php$ { ... }` as the second location for the last example. And you should understand that only PHP files are inaccessible with this configuration, any other file (JS, CSS, etc.) will be successfully requested from any folder.

Comment: Works perfectly. Thank you very much.